# Fake HttpSessionStateBase in MS Fakes

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, microsoft-fakes

I am writing a unit test to test an MVC controller method (CRUD operation). The controller method accepts the usernameIdentity from session for auditing purposes.

I am trying the following to setup the ShimHttpSessionStateBase:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void CategoryCreateTest()
    {
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            var controller = new WebcamsController();

            var category = new DataModel.Webcams.Category() { Name = "TestCategory" };
            var currentSessionWrapper = new HttpSessionStateWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Session);
            var session = new System.Web.Fakes.ShimHttpSessionStateBase(currentSessionWrapper);

            session.Instance.Add("usernameIdentity", "DOMAIN\\USERNAME");

            controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(controller);

            var result = controller.CategoryCreate(category);

            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(PartialViewResult));
        }
    }
```

I am not sure how to appropriately create the controllerContext so that the Session will be read in the controller method.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CategoryCreate([Bind(Include = "ID,Name")] Category category)
    {
        try
        {
            if (category != null
                && Validation.ValidNonNullableString(Session["usernameIdentity"].ToString(), 1, 60) && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                businessLayer.SetCategories(category, "Add", AuthenticationHandler.GetHostInternetProtocolAddress, Session["usernameIdentity"].ToString(), AuthenticationHandler.GetUserInternetProtocolAddress);

                return PartialView("CategoryList", businessLayer.GetCategoriesByCategory(0, AuthenticationHandler.GetHostInternetProtocolAddress));
            }

            return jsonResultHandler.JsonResultMessage("Failure", Properties.Resources.GlobalAttributeCreateFailed);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```